# What does *COM* stand for in objdump symbol table?

Tags: compilation, linker, elf, objdump, sections

There are a few section names in objdump output that have some unique names, like

- *ABS*
- *COM*
- *UND*

I guess *ABS* stands for ABSolute and denotes a symbol that doesn't belong to any section. External variables go to *COM* section. It seems that external functions go down to UNDefined. My questions are — what does COM stand for? What does it contain besides references to external variables? What are other sections like those two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed refers to "Common". From the [ELF spec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html):

> `SHN_COMMON` Symbols defined relative to this section are common symbols,
>   such as FORTRAN `COMMON` or unallocated C external variables.